# Prove something is affine?

Tags: affine-geometry

For any subspace $K$ and any point $u$, prove $K+u$ is affine. Or if you have an affine set $V$ and point $u$, then prove $V-u$ is a subspace.

Comment: how do you define those things?

Comment: A subspace is set of vectors that is closed under linear combinations. An affine set is a set of vectors that contains all affine combinations of its elements-affine combinations being any linear combination where multipliers sum to 1